# Can't View Adsense Despite It Being Active

Tags: google-analytics, blogger, adsense

Hey guys i have a blogger blog recently Google connected me with adsense but unfortunately it's been 3 weeks still. no ads can be seen kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Remove `google_ad_slot = "";` and `ca-pub` also from you google AdSense code after that your add will be show.